# Converting String to Double in Java

Tags: java, string, casting, double

I am having an issue with an error I am getting when I compile my program. The only issue is that it needs a double and I have a String. I tried to cast it as a double (both variables), but that didn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated. Here are the lines of code the issue is coming from. Both qualityPoints and sumOfHours are integers and GPA is a double. The error is on the third line.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
//GPA = (qualityPoints / sumOfHours);
GPA = df.format (((double)qualityPoints) /(double)(sumOfHours));
```

Error Code:

```
GPACalculator.java:123: error: incompatible types
GPA = df.format (((double)qualityPoints) /(double)(sumOfHours));
                  ^
required: double
found:    String
1 error
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is `qualityPoints` and `sumOfHours`?

Comment: You aren't converting a `String` to a `Double` in this code, you are converting a `double` to a `String.` The fact that you're trying to convert a `String` to a double (not `Double`) is the *problem.* -1 for not knowing what you're talking about.

Comment: No, I know what I was converting, it was a typo on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPA = Double.parseDouble(df.format (((double)qualityPoints) /(double)(sumOfHours)));

```
    int qualityPoints = 0;
    int sumOfHours = 0; 
    double GPA = 0;

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    GPA = Double.parseDouble(df.format (((double)qualityPoints) /(double)(sumOfHours)));
```

No compilation error for this.

Comment: I have tried that and that still doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: What's the error you getting now? Also, can you provide the declaration of these variables please?

Comment: Yes I will, I did in my description:

Comment: int qualityPoints = 0;

Comment: int sumOfHours = 0;             double GPA = 0;

Comment: Then it must compile correctly.

Comment: It was making me wait "1" minute

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you have a valid double value in `qualityPoints` string then you can try to use `Double.valueOf(String s)` method :

```
GPA = df.format ((Double.valueOf(qualityPoints)) /(double)(sumOfHours));
```

Comment: Its still giving me the exact same error.

Comment: @codeFinatic Do the same for sumOfHours variable

Comment: df.format() would return String and hence cannot be assigned to GPA directly.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
GPA = df.format ( Double.valueOf(qualityPoints) / Double.valueOf(sumOfHours) );
```

Comment: The format() would return String, so the result also needs to be converted to double if GPA is declared as double.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It gives me the exact error as I posted in original post.